# share home files but not preferences

Tags: display, users

I would like to know if it is possible to make a symbolic link between the home folders of two users so they both have access to documents, audio, photos, etc ... read and write, but actually have their own physical home folders for personal preferences... 
Here is why I want this: I am running Ubuntu Gnome on my MacBook 13". I sometimes run my 50" HDTV as a monitor, so of course my visual preferences (text scaling, etc.) is different from when I use my laptop screen.
I would like to know if I can create a new user, symbolic link the personal files so I can access everything from both users, but log in to different users for different visual setups.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of visual setups you are using that you need two different users?

Answer (score 1):

that function is fulfilled by the “public folder” that each account has, just make sure the folder's permissions and sharing are properly set. (read only, read and write etc)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. The OP is specifically asking how to have two users share the folders in Home name Documents, Video, etc., but not share hardware configuration files. Your suggestion may (or may not) be part of the answer, you might be able to add some specific steps for the OP.

Comment: Theason I need these two setups is because when I use the same configuration for my television that I use with my laptop, all the text is too small ... and vice versa, if I use my setup that I use for TV while using the laptop screen, the text is too large. So depending on if I use my television or my laptop, I would use a different user.